# Sql посчитать записи

Tags: sql

Есть у меня такие таблицы
users_new
nextpay_orders

В юзерах у меня есть колонка referal , где есть значения начинающиеся с префикса yad

В nextpay_orders у меня колонка amount - кол-во денег к примеру, и customer - ид пользователя, равен users.id

Вот суть запроса в том быть должна, что мне нужно вывести сумму из nextpay_orders если users_new.id равен nextpay_orders.customer и users_new.referal равен LIKE '%yad%', название реферала равному сумме этой, и кол-во рефералов в users_new.referal

Есть такой запрос

```
SELECT sum(nextpay_orders.amount) sum, users_new.referal ref_name, count(users_new.referal) cReferal 
   FROM `nextpay_orders`
   INNER JOIN `users_new` 
   ON users_new.id=nextpay_orders.customer
   WHERE users_new.referal LIKE '%yad%'
   GROUP BY users_new.referal
```

Мне выводит вот такой ответ

```
sum    ref_name cReferal    
3162   yad1     17    
1215   yad11    9
```

Все вроде бы хорошо, но проблема в том, что вот количество каждого не соответствует действительности.
У меня кол-во рефералов yad1 = 84,  а yad11 = 22

Как правильно написать запрос ?..

2 Запроса можно, что бы второй конкретно шел на вывод кол-ва рефералов, но хотелось бы все в одном, если реально конечно

Comment: попробуйте вместо `count(users_new.referal)` использовать `count(*)`

Comment: + у вас INNER JOIN выдает только совпадающие строки из двух таблиц

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас количество рефералов не соответствует скорее всего потому, что не у всех рефералов существуют записи в таблице `orders`. Вы используете `inner join`, а он возвращает только те записи у которых есть соответствия в обеих таблицах.

Можно поменять запрос так, чтобы он брал всех рефералов начинающихся с `yad` и брал `amount` только для тех, для кого смог найти. Для этого `inner join` можно заменить на `left join`:

```
select sum(no.amount) sum, un.referal ref_name, count(distinct un.id, un.referal) cReferal
from `users_new` un
left join `nextpay_orders` no on no.customer = un.id
where un.referal like '%yad%'
group by un.referal
```

[Sql fiddle пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/daec28/3).

Comment: Да, кстати все верно про INNER JOIN, это я протупил.
Ответ понятен, нужно написать 2ой запрос, так как мне нужно вывести конкретно всех у кого есть реферал yad...

Comment: @user190134 тот запрос, что я написал в ответе как раз и выведет всех у кого есть реферал yad%, даже если нет записи в orders. Второй запрос Вам не нужен.

Comment: Left join выводит так-же , 17 и 9, наверное все потому, что сравнение идете все же orders.customer=users.id

Comment: Вы в своём запросе поменяли inner join на left join и пробуете скоре всего. Так? Попробуйте этот запрос. В вашем варианте основная таблица это order, а в моем варианте это users.

Comment: Попробовал я Ваш запрос - мне выдает результаты 95 и 38, а вот в ручную написал запрос
SELECT count(*) FROM `users_new` WHERE referal = 'yad1';
Выводит 84, и 33

Comment: Значит у Вас в таблице `orders` по несколько записей на каждого пользователя (что, в принципе, ожидаемо), поэтому количество увеличивается. Я дополнил ответ, попробуйте теперь так.

Answer (score 1):

1. Запрос `LIKE "%...%"` имеет много шансов выполняться заметно дольше 
   чем запрос `LIKE "...%"`. В случае с MySQL это вообще приводит к FULL SCAN таблицы.
2. Запрос с виду вполне рабочий, значит вопрос к данным.

Хорошо бы получить пример сырых данных по запросу вида:

```
SELECT
  nextpay_orders.amount,
  users_new.referal
FROM `nextpay_orders`
LEFT JOIN `users_new`
  ON users_new.id=nextpay_orders.customer
WHERE users_new.referal LIKE '%yad%'
```

3. Хотелось бы уточнить диалект SQL

Comment: Ответ мой кроется в использовании INNER JOIN, теперь все ясно стало, почему выводит так.